# Linq to entity error unable to create constant value

Tags: entity-framework

I have a function to which I pass a string and then use linq to entity to check if the string value that I passed already exists in the database. For This purpose I have written this function.

```
    public static bool UserExistChk(String StrUserId) {
            using (SBVEntities dbcontx = new SBVEntities())
           {
                return dbcontx.Users.Contains(dbcontx.Users.FirstOrDefault(e => e.UserID == StrUserId));

           }
    }
```

But I get error-- Unable to create a constant value of type 'MySBVApp.Models.User'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Please help I am new to entity framework and linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Any` extension method for this:

```
public static bool UserExistChk(String StrUserId)
{
  using ( SBVEntities db = new SBVEntities() )
  {
    return db.Users.Any( o => o.UserID == StrUserId );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for.. Thanks a lot Nicholas Butler.

Comment: @Yagnesh.Dixit you're welcome :) There are some examples that might help you for LINQ to Objects and LINQ to Entities - google "101 LINQ samples"

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this.

```
           using (SBVEntities dbcontx = new SBVEntities())
           {
              return (dbcontx.Users
                             .FirstOrDefault(e => e.UserID == StrUserId) != null 
                             ? true : false); 
           }
```

Comment: Thanks spajce but that does not returns a bool value I have to check for null and then accordingly return a bool value.

Comment: Thanks a lot spajce but I was looking for something like contains that retruns bool value. (In short I was trying to avoid this extra code that you edited.) Anyways It worked and solved my problem thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
public static bool UserExistChk(String StrUserId) 
{
    using (SBVEntities dbcontx = new SBVEntities())
    {
        var query = from u in dbcontx.Users
                    where u.UserId.Contains(strUserId)
                    select u;
    }
    Return query.Count > 0
}
```